# How to find common elements between two tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two images with the same size of 128x128x128. They are binary images. I want to find the common position of 1's value in two images. For example, the position (2,2) in images 1 has value 1 and (2,2) in images 2 has value 1 that considered a common position. I have tried below code but it said that I cannot do the conversation. How should I fix it? This is my error that shows in `pos_common = tuple(set(pos_1) & set(pos_2))`

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

```
pos_1 = np.where(img1==1) #returns (array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 127]), array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 127]), array([  0,   1,   2, ..., 127]))
pos_2 = np.where(img2==1) # returns (array([  1,   4,   9, ..., 127]), array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 127]), array([  0,   1,   2, ..., 127]))
pos_common = tuple(set(pos_1) & set(pos_2)) # Error TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: where is the error coming from? your `np.where` or your `tuple`? Please revise your question if possible to include [mcve].

Comment: It from tuple(set...)

Answer (score 2):

-- Hey KimHee,

I would

1. Set all values in img1 and img2 that are not equal 1 to 0
2. Use numpy.multiply() to only retain ones where both matrices equal 1
3. Finally, apply np.where if you still need to

Here's the code I used to reproduce your problem (assumed simple 2d arrays):

```
img1 = np.array([[10,10,10,1,1,1,10], [10,10,10,1,10,10,10]])
img2 = np.array([[10,10,10,10,1,10,10], [10,10,10,1,10,10,10]])

img1[img1 != 1] = 0
img2[img2 != 1] = 0

pos_common = np.multiply(img1, img2)

np.where(pos_common == 1)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I found simple solution. It may help someone

```
pos_common = np.where((img1==1) & (img2==1))
```

Comment: simple solution, great work! Your original approach failed because the ndarray type isn't hashable. you could've compared each row in those arrays, and then combined them at teh end, but this solution is much better. Cheers.